# Joomla site working with github(or any other version control system)

Tags: github

I've never used github before although I was aware of it long time ago. More and more I feel the need to version control my joomla site. For example, sometimes I change lots of js/php/css files to try a new layout or new function, but later I decide it doesn't work out, so I need to go back to the old version. At this stage, I would have to do a lot of work to restore the site to a previous version. I am imagining with github it would be a lot easier. But the question is, how can I make my joomla site working with github? I don't even know if it is viable.

I know github is being used on module/component development, but can I use it on a whole website? Or just a small part of my website? Can I form a repository from a cutsom js file and a PHP file from one of the modules and a custom CSS file? Does anyone actually use github this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can of course use it for your website and is an amazing tool to track everything.

You can make your js changes and commit them so you can revert only your js changes.

You need to first setup a GIT Repo see:

https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/

Once setup you can import all the files of your current working site.

Once imported you can start tracking changes and so on, here is an intro to GIT:

http://www.sitepoint.com/git-for-beginners/

When you want to make changes do it, when you have finished zip it up and replace your site with the edited files. You therefore always have a record of changes.

I would personally suggest an ide for coding, like net beans for a free editor, or phpstorm which is my favourite buy a paid for IDE, it naturally shows deprecated functions and classes when creating a project with the whole Joomla! Site helping keep your code up to date and easily pointing out errors.

Comment: Thank you. Before digging in, I'd like to confirm a thing:So I can import all the files of a live site to GIT right? Later when I make changes to my live site, would GIT automatically pick up and record the change? I thought this was unlikely because that way GIT would have access to my server. On the other hand, if I have to have a local version of my site and GIT this local version, it would be much more time-consuming. So can this dilemma be solved?

Comment: Well, you will be working on a local copy on your computer for development purposes. Once these changes are done you push them to the live server correct? 

Then, you do exactly then same, apart from you do additional commits and pushes to track your work. GIThub then becomes a single place to view changes easily, and a source code backup :-).

For a live site with automatic deployment you can see:

http://toroid.org/git-website-howto